# How to create a typeahead menu in React and populate it with options from an Postgresql table?

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, express, frontend, typeahead

I'm using React, Node, Express, Postgresql for a simple project. The dropdown menu should have it's select options populated from a postgresql table.

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | sam |
| 2 | frank |
| 3 | joe |
| 4 | sally |

I have tried creating a typeahead menu based on the plugin below:

```
https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead
```

Below is the typeahead code I tried using

```
<Fragment>
      <Form.Group>
        <Form.Label>Single Selection</Form.Label>
        <Typeahead
          id="basic-typeahead-single"
          labelKey="name"
          onChange={setSingleSelections}
          options={options}
          placeholder="Choose a state..."
          selected={singleSelections}
        />
      </Form.Group>
</Fragment>
```

Just running that alone gave me some errors, so I changed it up like so:

```
<div className="form-group">
                <div className="form-label">Single Selection</div>
                <Typeahead
                    id="basic-typeahead-single"
                    labelKey="name"
                    onChange={setSingleSelections}
                    options={options}
                    placeholder="Choose a state..."
                    selected={singleSelections}
                />
            </div>
```

This is where I'm stuck as I'm not sure how to modify the code to populate the options with column name from the table above. In the past I had trouble using datalist as there was no way to limit the display results, so my dropdown menu would extend past the app screen. Honestly any and all help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your `options` as an array of objects and pass them as a prop to `Typeahead`.

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const [singleSelections, setSingleSelections] = useState([]);

  const options = [
    { id: 1, name: "sam" },
    { id: 2, name: "frank" },
    { id: 3, name: "joe" },
    { id: 4, name: "sally" },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <div className="form-label">Single Selection</div>
      <Typeahead
        id="basic-typeahead-single"
        labelKey="name"
        onChange={setSingleSelections}
        options={options}
        placeholder="Choose a person..."
        selected={singleSelections}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I'm not familiar with this API, but it appears that you can customize how the options are rendered in the menu according to [these docs](http://ericgio.github.io/react-bootstrap-typeahead/#rendering).